# Ошибка кодировки при компиляции Gradle проекта

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, кодировка, gradle

Имеется Java-проект на `Gradle`. При выполнении команды `./gradlew build` возникает ошибка компиляции:

> unmappable character for encoding Cp1251

В проекте есть строки на кириллице, и для всех файлов проекта задана кодировка `UTF-8`, но ошибка всё равно возникает. Я добавил в `build.gradle` следующие строки:

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Никаких изменений. Единственное, что помогает - это ручное изменение кодировки в некоторых файлах с кириллицей с `UTF-8` на `windows-1251`, но это не выглядит, как чистое решение. В качестве рабочей системы использую Windows 8.1.

Каким образом я могу решить данную проблему?

**UPD от 25.05.22:** Попытался подключить и использовать плагин `application` таким образом:

```
plugins {
    id "application"
}

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"]
```

но это также не даёт никаких изменений. При билде снова возникают ошибки из-за нескольких строк кода, в которых используется кириллица. Для примера вот одна из ошибок:

```
error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
{"╨п╨╜╨▓", "╨д╨╡╨▓", "╨Ь╨░╤А", "╨Р╨┐╤А", "╨Ь╨░╨╣", "╨?╤О╨╜", "╨?╤О╨╗", "╨Р╨▓╨│", "╨б╨╡╨╜", "╨Ю╨║╤В", "╨Э╨╛╤П", "╨Ф╨╡╨║"};
```

тогда как исходный код:

```
{"Янв", "Фев", "Мар", "Апр", "Май", "Июн", "Июл", "Авг", "Сен", "Окт", "Ноя", "Дек"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка кодировки решается при помощи следующего кода, добавленного в `build.gradle`:

```groovy
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8' // устанавливает кодировку для компилируемого кода
javadoc.options.encoding = 'UTF-8' // устанавливает кодировку для генерируемой документации
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Это распространённое решение в интернете, но оно не работало в моём случае. Так как у меня многомодульный проект, я поместил эти настройки в главный `build.gradle`, находящийся в корне. Однако, ошибки кодировки всё равно возникали с подпроектами. По какой-то причине настройки родительского проекта не наследовались, поэтому было два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Добавить настройки в `build.gradle` каждого модуля, где есть проблемы с кодировкой.
2. Создать `groovy`-плагин для подключения в `build.gradle` каждого модуля и добавить настройки в него.

Я выбрал второй вариант, потому что у меня уже существовал самописный плагин, который подключался в каждый модуль проекта.